# In swift the UIDynamicAnimation takes too long to pause

Tags: swift, uidynamicbehavior

I have a view that has UIDynamicItems interact with each other, however I don't want them to deform upon collision, thus I set the elasticity to 0. But this didn't work the items are still squeezed and bouncing around, by a small amount. When I try to reset the shape of the view when the `dynamicAnimationDidPause()` but it takes too long because of the vibrations and bouncing. How can I set them to perfectly inelastic? Do I need to switch to a different framework?

What I've done so far

```
private let collider:UICollisionBehavior = {
    let collider = UICollisionBehavior()
    collider.setTranslatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary(with: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: -300, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    //collider.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    return collider
}()

var cellBehaviour:UIDynamicItemBehavior = {
    let cellBehaviour = UIDynamicItemBehavior()
    cellBehaviour.allowsRotation = false
    cellBehaviour.elasticity = 0
    return cellBehaviour
}()
```

Sorry I'm new to programming so I don't know the exact terms. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: public var elasticity: CGFloat // Usually between 0 (inelastic) and 1 (collide elastically)
I took that directly from Apple's Object... I believe you are not implementing the cell's behavior properly or the value is overridden by something else you do. I don't have a direct answer because I am experience with Swift but have not used ItemBehavior classes personally.

Comment: Thank you Sethmr, I did set the elasticity to 0 and I could see difference when I set it to 1, 0.1 or even -1 which seemed to break physics.. but when it's set to 0 it doesn't feel like inelastic. Perhaps my understanding of elasticity is wrong. What I want is candy-crush-ish behaviour - the dropped candies stops and stays.. maybe that's more advanced. For now I'll investigate what you've said. Thank you :)